# \newcommand that restricts the value of an argument

Tags: conditionals, optional-arguments

When defining a macro, is it possible to restrict the value of an argument, so that if the thing followed it is a number, then it takes it as an argument, but if it is not, then it is just empty.

To be concrete, I defined

```
\newcommand{\R}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}}
```

for a real vector space, so the `\R2` and `\R3` give the 2-dim and 3-dim real spaces respectively. But what do I do if I want to input `\R` only?

Comment: Insert `$\R{}$`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an expl3 "solution".  It will fail if you try to type something like `\Rt` and gobbles spaces so that `\R 4` will take 4 as an argument.  I'm not sure how a 2 digit superscript could be done using your syntax (no argument), so I added an optional argument in square brackets for that case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \my_R:n #1
{
    \ensuremath{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \R { o }
{
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
        {
            \peek_catcode:NTF 1
                {
                    \my_R:n
                }
                {
                    \ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}\ 
                }
        }
        {
            \my_R:n {#1}
        }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
This is \R and this is \R3 and this is \R 4 and here is \R[23].
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't notice that this was such an oldie!

Comment: I'd much prefer `\newcommand\R[1][]{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}`, which is easier and has a clearer syntax: `\R` or `\R[2]`.

Comment: @egreg I agree!  The asker seemed to want a no argument syntax though `\R2` etc.  Without defining separate commands for each possible dimension, I couldn't think of an easier way to do it :(